# PHP - session_id() gives me HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, apache, cgi, sessionid

Running Apache with PHP as FastCGI.

**serverinfo.php**:

```
if (isset($_GET['session'])) {
    session_id($_GET['session']);
    session_start();
    die('You got here');
}
```

i won't even get to session_start() because session_id() will hang the "thread".
This is the scenario:

Page **[serverinfo.php]** shows server info, where you can update info as well.
When updating the info, a AJAX call is made to **[update.php]**, when everything is updated **[update.php]** is supposed to return the same data shown in **[serverinfo.php]** just to "refresh" the "page" with the new data, this is done by:

**update.php**:

```
if($update) {
    $serverinfo = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/serverinfo.php?session=' . session_id() . '&name=' . $_GET['name']);
    print $serverinfo;
}
```

The reason why i want to re-use the internal $_SESSION is because i need to access data about the client for a specific session, such as username and other important data.
Otherwise serverinfo.php will just give me: "Login!" which it's supposed to do :)

I could do:
include_once('serverinfo.php');
and pass the $_GET data some how but i'm not quite sure if that would work or be all that efficient :)

**Accesslog from Apache**:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2012:11:03:15 +0100] "GET update.php?source=serverinfo&name=test HTTP/1.1" 500 544
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2012:11:03:15 +0100] "GET serverinfo.php?session=<session_id>&name=test HTTP/1.0" 500 544
```

This simply shows that update.php actually completes it's updates and tries to call serverinfo.php but it fails with Internal Server error.

**apache error log**:

```
[Wed Feb 15 11:03:55 2012] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: read timeout from pipe
[Wed Feb 15 11:03:55 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: serverinfo.php
```

And here's the *global* **error log**:

```
[Wed Feb 15 11:04:04 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5584 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Comment: `update.py` looks an awful lot like PHP to me, not Python...

Comment: Haha, damnit.. i'm a Python developer most of my days, i just defaulted to .py when ending my file extensions :) corrected that (thank you)

Comment: So where do you get the 500 error, from `serverinfo.php` or `update.php`? Also check the Apache error logs - from a HTTP 500, PHP or otherwise, there should be a message logged telling you why it errored out.

Comment: The error occurs in serverinfo.php within the code i posted at the beginning of my problem statement. Also, those 5 rows of code is located at the very top of serverinfo.php and i located the issue to be "session_id()" without a doubt.

Comment: Can you do a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in front of the faulty call? It may give more information about the error

Comment: @Torxed Maybe I don't fully understand, but why are you sending the sessid with GET manually? Once the session cookie is set, the browser takes care of sending it, and you only have to call `session_start()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, reading between the lines I think I know what's going on here.

Contrary to what you have ascertained, I think you will find it is actually `session_start()` that is hanging, and the cause of the 500 error is that the time limit eventually expires.

The reason `session_start()` is hanging is because `update.php` still has a lock on the session file. While you have an open session, the file is locked by the script that has it open. You can release this lock by closing the session data with [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) - but this is probably not what you want to do here.

I would say that what you want to do is what you have suggested, and `include 'serverinfo.php';` instead of calling it through HTTP. This will be more efficient - `include` does considerably less work than a HTTP request - and it will resolve the session problem. You do not need to "pass" `$_GET` to `serverinfo.php` for two reasons:

1. `$_GET` is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). It is automatically available in every possible scope within the execution of a given script.
2. When a file is included, it inherits the scope from which it was included. This means that even if `$_GET` *weren't* superglobal it would *still* be available in the included file, as it is available in the scope from which the file was included.

If you include the file, you also don't need to worry about making the session data available, `$_SESSION` has the same superglobal properties as `$_GET`.

All you need to do is:

**update.php**

```
if ($update) {
    include 'serverinfo.php';
}
```

**serverinfo.php**

```
die('You got here');
// $_GET['name'] has the same value here as it does in update.php
// Similarly, all the $_SESSION data is automatically available here
```

Comment: Most often the simplest solution can create wonders..
This is one of those times, i don't even know why i didn't try this before i bothered you guys.

Again, thank you! Worked perfectly.
Now all that's left is some AJAX code that's not being executed as it should :P